# How to add sections titles to the headers and to the toc?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

I am trying to customize a template initially designed for novels. I have added to it sections and I would like to see, as headers, on the left page, the title of the book, at the center of the page, and, on the right page and at the center of the page, the title of the chapter. I'd like especially to see all the subsections numbered in my toc. How could I do that?

This is my mwe:

```
\documentclass[smalldemyvopaper,10pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf]{Alegreya,AlegreyaSans}


\usepackage{lipsum}

% PACKAGE DEFINITION
% typographical packages
\usepackage{microtype} % for micro-typographical adjustments
\usepackage{setspace} % for line spacing
\usepackage{lettrine} % for drop caps and awesome chapter beginnings
\usepackage{titlesec} % for manipulation of chapter titles

% for placeholder text
\usepackage{lipsum} % to generate Lorem Ipsum




% other
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{hologo}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{showframe}
% PHYSICAL DOCUMENT SETUP
% media settings
\setstocksize{8.5in}{5.675in}
\settrimmedsize{8.5in}{5.5in}{*}
\setbinding{0.175in}
\setlrmarginsandblock{0.611in}{1.222in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{0.722in}{1.545in}{*}

% defining the title and the author
%\title{\LaTeX{} ePub Template}
%\title{\textsc{How I Started to Love {\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\LaTeX{}}}}
\title{A title}

\author{My name}
\newcommand{\ISBN}{0-000-00000-2}
\newcommand{\press}{Nom de l'éditeur}

% custom second title page
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\halftitlepage{\begingroup % Misericords, T&H p 153
  \setlength\drop{0.1\textheight}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{\drop}
  \rule{\textwidth}{0in}\par
  {\Large\textsc\thetitle\par}
  \rule{\textwidth}{0in}\par
  \vfill
  \end{center}
\endgroup}
\makeatother

% custom title page
\thispagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\newlength\drop
\newcommand*\titleM{\begingroup % Misericords, T&H p 153
  \setlength\drop{0.15\textheight}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{\drop}
  \rule{\textwidth}{0in}\par
  {\HUGE\textsc\thetitle\par}
  \rule{\textwidth}{0in}\par
  {\Large\textit\theauthor\par}
  \vfill
  {\Large\scshape\press}
  \end{center}
\endgroup}
\makeatother

% chapter title manipulation
% padding with zero
%\renewcommand*\thechapter{\ifnum\value{chapter}<10 0\fi\arabic{chapter}}
% chapter title display
\titleformat
{\chapter}
[display]
{\normalfont\scshape\LARGE}
{\huge\thechapter\centering}
{0pt}
{\vspace{18pt}\centering}[\vspace{22pt}]

% typographical settings for the body text
\setlength{\parskip}{0em}
\linespread{1.09}

% HEADER AND FOOTER MANIPULATION
  % for normal pages
  \nouppercaseheads
  \headsep = 0.16in
  \makepagestyle{mystyle} 
  \setlength{\headwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}
  \makerunningwidth{mystyle}{\headwidth}
  \makeevenhead{mystyle}{}{\textsf{\scriptsize\scshape\thetitle}}{}
  \makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{\textsf{\scriptsize\scshape\leftmark}}{}
  \makeevenfoot{mystyle}{}{\textsf{\scriptsize\thepage}}{}
  \makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{\textsf{\scriptsize\thepage}}{}
  \makeatletter
  \makepsmarks{mystyle}{%
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{\@chapapp\ }{.\ }}
  \makeatother
  % for pages where chapters begin
  \makepagestyle{plain}
  \makerunningwidth{plain}{\headwidth}
  \makeevenfoot{plain}{}{}{}
  \makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{}
  \pagestyle{mystyle}
% END HEADER AND FOOTER MANIPULATION

% table of contents customisation
\renewcommand\contentsname{\normalfont\scshape Contents}
\renewcommand\cftchapterfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}{\centering\Huge}



% layout check and fix
\checkandfixthelayout
\fixpdflayout

% BEGIN THE DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
% the half title page
%\halftitlepage
\cleardoublepage
% the title page
\titleM

% begin front matter
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\chapter{Introduction}

\mainmatter
\part{A part}

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{A section}
\lipsum



\end{document}
```

Comment: off-topic: (i) it is sufficient to load each package once (ii) `lettrine` is integrated to memoir, so it is no need to load again, (iii) `memoir` provide similar facilities as `titlesec`, so i would rather exploit `memoir` ... (iv) for your problem see *7.3.1 Example pagestyles* on page 111 in `memoir` manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all I highly recommend to take into account @Zarko remarks as the problem you are facing is largely due to some incompatibilities between the `memoir` class and the `titlesec` package.
2. The `\thetitle` command defined by the `memoir` class is redifined by the `titlesec` package so we need to store its value before. So we define a new macro with `edef\TheTitle{\thetitle}` and use it to set the headers

   ```
   \makeevenhead{mystyle}{}{\textsf{\scriptsize\scshape\TheTitle}}{}
   \makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{\textsf{\scriptsize\scshape\leftmark}}{}
   ```
3. To   number the `subsection`s and see them in the toc:

%

```
 \maxsecnumdepth{subsection}
 \maxtocdepth{subsection}
```

**The complete code**

```
\documentclass[smalldemyvopaper, 10pt, twoside, onecolumn, openright, extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf]{Alegreya,AlegreyaSans}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% PACKAGE DEFINITION
% typographical packages
\usepackage{microtype} % for micro-typographical adjustments
\usepackage{setspace} % for line spacing
\usepackage{lettrine} % for drop caps and awesome chapter beginnings
\usepackage{titlesec} % for manipulation of chapter titles

% for placeholder text
\usepackage{lipsum} % to generate Lorem Ipsum

% other
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{hologo}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{showframe}
% PHYSICAL DOCUMENT SETUP
% media settings
\setstocksize{8.5in}{5.675in}
\settrimmedsize{8.5in}{5.5in}{*}
\setbinding{0.175in}
\setlrmarginsandblock{0.611in}{1.222in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{0.722in}{1.545in}{*}

% defining the title and the author
%\title{\LaTeX{} ePub Template}
%\title{\textsc{How I Started to Love {\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\LaTeX{}}}}
\title{The book title}

\author{My name}
\newcommand{\ISBN}{0-000-00000-2}
\newcommand{\press}{Nom de l'éditeur}

\edef\TheTitle{\thetitle}

% custom second title page
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\halftitlepage{\begingroup % Misericords, T&H p 153
  \setlength\drop{0.1\textheight}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{\drop}
  \rule{\textwidth}{0in}\par
  {\Large\textsc\thetitle\par}
  \rule{\textwidth}{0in}\par
  \vfill
  \end{center}
\endgroup}
\makeatother

% custom title page
\thispagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\newlength\drop
\newcommand*\titleM{\begingroup % Misericords, T&H p 153
  \setlength\drop{0.15\textheight}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{\drop}
  \rule{\textwidth}{0in}\par
  {\HUGE\textsc\thetitle\par}
  \rule{\textwidth}{0in}\par
  {\Large\textit\theauthor\par}
  \vfill
  {\Large\scshape\press}
  \end{center}
\endgroup}
\makeatother

% chapter title manipulation
% padding with zero
%\renewcommand*\thechapter{\ifnum\value{chapter}<10 0\fi\arabic{chapter}}
% chapter title display
\titleformat
{\chapter}
[display]
{\normalfont\scshape\LARGE}
{\huge\thechapter\centering}
{0pt}
{\vspace{18pt}\centering}[\vspace{22pt}]

% typographical settings for the body text
\setlength{\parskip}{0em}
\linespread{1.09}

% HEADER AND FOOTER MANIPULATION
  % for normal pages
  \nouppercaseheads
  \headsep = 0.16in
  \makepagestyle{mystyle} 
  \setlength{\headwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax}
  \makerunningwidth{mystyle}{\headwidth}
  \makeevenhead{mystyle}{}{\textsf{\scriptsize\scshape\TheTitle}}{}
  \makeoddhead{mystyle}{}{\textsf{\scriptsize\scshape\leftmark}}{}
  \makeevenfoot{mystyle}{}{\textsf{\scriptsize\thepage}}{}
  \makeoddfoot{mystyle}{}{\textsf{\scriptsize\thepage}}{}
  \makeatletter
  \makepsmarks{mystyle}{%
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{\@chapapp\ }{.\ }}
  \makeatother
  % for pages where chapters begin
  \makepagestyle{plain}
  \makerunningwidth{plain}{\headwidth}
  \makeevenfoot{plain}{}{}{}
  \makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{}
  \pagestyle{mystyle}
% END HEADER AND FOOTER MANIPULATION

% table of contents customisation
\renewcommand\contentsname{\normalfont\scshape Contents}
\renewcommand\cftchapterfont{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}{\centering\Huge}

% layout check and fix
\checkandfixthelayout
\fixpdflayout

% BEGIN THE DOCUMENT
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
% the half title page
%\halftitlepage
\cleardoublepage
% the title page
\titleM

% begin front matter
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\maxtocdepth{subsection}
\maxsecnumdepth{subsection}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\mainmatter
\part{A part}

\chapter{A chapter}

\section{A section}

\subsection{A subsection}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It works, but for section only, not for subsections nor subsubsections. How could I dot that?

Comment: @domi What do you want in the headers *chapters*, *sections*, *subsections*, *subsubsections* ,... ???

Comment: On the left, the title of the book, on the right, the title of the chapter. But, I'd like especially to see all the subsections in my toc.

Comment: @domi It seams to me  that your question has changed so maybe you should update your post.

Comment: thanks for your precious help, but I had to modify again my request. I wanted to say : on the left page, not on the left of the page...

Comment: OK. It works. But the subsection and the subsubsection are not numbered nor in the  toc nor in the body.

Comment: @domi see updates